# Why does my CAPTCHA code fail?

Tags: php, captcha

I created a captcha for a contact form. Everything works fine but whatever the number I enter into the captcha form it always shows invalid captcha

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['norobot']))
 {
  if(md5($_POST['norobot']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2'])
  {
  echo "Validation Success";
  $_SESSION['name'] = $name ;
  $_SESSION['phone_no'] = $phone;
  $_SESSION['mailid'] = $mailid;
  $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
  $_SESSION['category'] = $category;
  header("Location:thankyou.php");
  }
  else
   {
   $Error = 'Invalid CAPTCHA';
   }
 }
}
?>
```

can any one say what the solution is?

Comment: At the time the captcha image is displayed, what's the value of $_SESSION['randomnr2'] (and don't assume, get your code to display it along with the captcha). When you come to check the POST, again, dump _SESSION['randomnr2'] and $_POST['norobot'] to get more clues. You've not posted enough code for anyone to be able to help you beyond this, but I would suspect you are regenerating $_SESSION['randomnr2']

Comment: Might just be missing `session_start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing $_SESSION['randomnr2'] ?  Are you md5()'ing it?

Might help to see all the code.